# Getting content of file from path

Tags: ios, swift, nsdata, uidocument

I am struggling with few lines of code which is embarassing. I have read many answers but none seems to work. In my function I get a file path from picked document:

```
func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentAt url: URL) {

        let urlString = url.path
        let fileName = url.lastPathComponent
        let ref = DataService.instance.imagesStorageRef.child("\(fileName)")
         var contents = try? Data(contentsOf: url)
         print("contents: \(contents)")



        let uploadTask = ref.putData(contents! as Data, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, error) in ...}
}
```

> file:///private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile%20Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/nutella.jpg
>   contents: nil

Then i try to get the content of that file path so i can pass it to upload function which uploads it to firebase. However, no matter how i try to get that content i always get nil value. Please guide me into proper direction.

Comment: Use a `do/catch` and see what the error is when trying to get the contents of the URL.

Comment: And what mode did you use for the document picker? Was it "import" or "open"?

Comment: I will try do/catch. I use „open” mode.

Comment: Use "import", not "open". Read the documentation about the difference between the two.

Comment: "Import" and do/catch works perfect. Thank you so much. I have also encountered error:
[DocumentManager] The view service did terminate with error: Error Domain=_UIViewServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)" UserInfo={Terminated=disconnect method}
Do you know why? I tried to work it out but no success there.

Comment: @LeoDabus That's a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

One more way which may help to you. for that you need to convert that document into data form and then you can send it to server

Here I paste sample code..

```
 func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentAt url: URL) {
        let fileURL = url as URL
        print("The Url is : \(fileURL)")
        let fileNameWithoutExtension = fileURL.pathExtension
        print("fileNameWithoutExtension: \(fileNameWithoutExtension)")
        do {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: fileURL)
            print("data=\(data)")
            //TODO: call upload API
            self.sendAttachments()
        }
        catch {/* error handling here */}
    }
```